# How to calculate nPr mod m, when m is a prime number?

Tags: factorial, modular-arithmetic

I need to find out the value of nPr%m.

This is the approach I used.

Find, n!%m, (n-r)!%m and divide them

However, for certain cases, (n-r)!%m is greater than n!%m, so the resultant nPr is 0.

What do I need to do then?

Comment: That approach isn't going to work. `(a%m)/(b%m)` does not necessarily equal `(a/b)%m`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a math question than a programming question, but anyway.

Note that

```
n! / (n - r)! = n * (n - 1) * ... * (n - r + 1)
```

Now for multiplication,

```
(a * b * c) % m = (((a * b) % m) * c) % m
```

i.e. rather than `mod m`ing the entire product, you can `mod m` the intermediate result of any multiplication of two factors in the product.

I won't provide the full code here, but hopefully this will be enough for you to figure it out.

Comment: Can you help me with this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254901/having-difficulty-in-computing-factorialn-mod-m-when-n-gets-large